# how can i make my input no. be like 1010 not 1 "\n" 0 "\n" 1 "\n" 0 "\n"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   int array_size, array[100];

   cout << "Enter length of number you want to input ";
   cin >> array_size;

   cout << "Enter the inputs" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
            cin >> array[i];

            if (array[i] == 0){
               array[i] = 1;                          
            }else{
               array[i] = 0;      
            }
       } 

       cout << "output" << endl;
       for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
                cout << array[i];
           }
           cout << endl;
           system("PAUSE");
           return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Please edit the tile to something like "Remove the EOLN character from the output" then ask the question within the body. I think it will improve the search-ability of the question and probably will show you additional questions with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input to a string and parse the numbers from that string.

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
    if (input.at(i) == '0') {
        array[i] = 1;
    } else {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't get it lol im newbie :/
the program is about giving the output of the input.. input by the user
example
input : 1010
output : 0101

can help?

Comment: @RavenRama Works as expected? You input 1 in the array where user entered 0.

Comment: yep it does. the program should accept atleast 20 input.
if the input 1 output 0 and vice versa